# regex: replace espaces before :!? with &nbsp; if it does not exist

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to replace space by `&nbsp;` if it does not exist :

```
input: "hello!", expect: "hello&nbsp!;"
input: "hello !", expect: "hello&nbsp!;"
input: "hello  !", expect: "hello&nbsp!;"
input: "hello&nbsp;!", expect: "hello&nbsp!"
```

for the last line actually I get

```
input: "hello&nbsp;!", expect: "hello&nbsp;&nbsp;!"
```

It adds an extra `&nbsp;` and I would like to avoid it

Here is my code so far:

```
text.replace(/ *([:!?])/g, "&nbsp;\$1";
```

Comment: This kind of replacements are usually done in two steps: first do the replacement as you do it now then remove the duplicates (replace two `&nbsp;` with only one). It can be done in a single step too, with a regex that contains assertions but it's easier this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by matching optional `&nbsp;`s before the spaces and punctuation and discarding them in the substitution:

```js
const strs = [
'hello!',
'hello !',
'hello  !',
'hello&nbsp;!',
'hello&nbsp;&nbsp;!',
'hello&nbsp;&nbsp;  !'
];

console.log(strs.map(s => s.replace(/(?:&nbsp;)* *([:!?])/, '&nbsp;$1')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```js
.replace(/(?:&nbsp;|\s)*([:!?])/, '&nbsp;$1')
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/FFkNWL/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                        ' '
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [:!?]                    any character of: ':', '!', '?'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
```

**Javascript code**:

```js
const strs = [
'hello!',
'hello !',
'hello  !',
'hello&nbsp;!',
'hello&nbsp;&nbsp;!',
'hello&nbsp;&nbsp;  !'
];

console.log(strs.map(s => s.replace(/(?:&nbsp;|\s)*([:!?])/, '&nbsp;$1')))
```